# add an exit button to .navigationBarItems

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm a beginner at swiftui. I need to add an exit button to .navigationBarItems. How can I add this button in the parent NavigationView to show this button on all children's views?

// a simple example on my question

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
                TabView{
                    SubExampleViewOne()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                    SubExampleViewTwo()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
                            Text("Bookmark")
                        }
                }
            }
            //here I have added a toolbar and it is perfectly visible in tabitem
            //this is what I am trying to achieve, the visibility of the button on all pages
            .toolbar {
               
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    ButtonExitView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

something strange - if I add NavigationLink in this way, Image and Text("Home") are visible twice
and the ToolbarItem is no longer on the new page

```
struct SubExampleViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is hime page!")
            .padding()
        NavigationLink(destination: SubExampleViewThree()){
            Text("Navigation link")
        }
    }
}

struct SubExampleViewTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct SubExampleViewThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Navigation link")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ButtonExitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right.circle")})
    }
}
```

after learning about TabView, I thought that there should be a similar solution for the top of the page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ChrisR - if that's the answer - then create an answer, please - comments are for clarificaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the button to each child view separately.

And you should use `.toolbar` and `.toolBarItem` because `.navigationBarItems` is deprecated.